# FragmentStatePagerAdapter like view in windows phone

Tags: android, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to windows phone development. I am trying to develop an application which will have the ability of viewing pictures by swiping to right/left (like 9Gag). I am looking for a way to do that using FragmentStatePagerAdapter like view but i didn't find anything that does the work like it. What is the similar view like FragmentStatePagerAdapter in windows environment?.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a normal ListBox an add the images as Items.

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
          <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" 
                               Stretch = "Fill"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Microsoft did create a control for this! It's called the MediaViewer Class, but it's a difficult one to use.
It's however the closest representation of the actual control used in the WP camera app!
It was first featured in the [Basic Lens app sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b) and provided as a nuget package [PhoneMediaViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneMediaViewer)

I tried to toy with it a bit on [my github here...](https://github.com/Depechie/ImageSliderMediaClass)

Hope these code examples help